# Generating PublicKey from Base64 encoded String

Tags: android

I need to use PublicKey to encrypt session key but I have public key as Base64 encoded string so I tried to convert it as :

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // or "EC" or whatever
byte[] keyBytes = _publicKey.getBytes();
byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.decode(keyBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpecs = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
Log.v("", "X509  KS" + publicKeySpecs);
publicKey = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpecs);
```

But I am getting public key as null value and getting exception as :

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

If anyone has idea how to do it or have working code then please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956647/rsa-encrypt-with-base64-encoded-public-key-in-android

Comment: The error means that your key bytes are not understood (wrong format). There may be a character encoding problem when you do `_publicKey.getBytes()` or the key is really the wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi guys I generated `Public Key` from `Base64` encoded String .

after wondering for few days this code worked for me.

```
String _publicKey= base64encoded_publickey;


    // InputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        // Receiving side

        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(_publicKey, Base64.DEFAULT);

        fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);

        // Print the decoded string

        String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);


        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory
                .getInstance(CERTIFICATE_TYPE);
        // certFactory.
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory
                .generateCertificate(fileInputStream);
        publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
        Log.d("TAG", "Public key of the certificate:" + publicKey);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not intialize encryption module",
                e);
    } finally {
        if (keyStream != null) {
            try {
                keyStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you...Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

well, last time it worked for me (I used bouncyCastle library..), you might need to modify it if it doesn't suit your need..

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
KeyPair kp = null;

keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");

ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("brainpoolp160r1");
keyGen.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

kp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

**EDIT**:
(oops my bad, that's for initial generation..)
at that time I stored them as one..
and I need to convert the Base64 string back to array of `byte` first, and split them into part 1 and part 2..

```
private void splitKeyPair (byte[] thekeypair, byte[] part1, byte[] part2)
{
    System.arraycopy(thekeypair, 0, part1, 0, 68);
    System.arraycopy(thekeypair, 68, part2, 0, 115);
}

byte[] part1 = new byte[68];
byte[] part2 = new byte[115];
splitKeyPair(inputBuffer, part1, part2);

fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
kp = new KeyPair(fact.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(part1)),
                    fact.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(part2)));
```

hope it helps..
*note: the size might vary, depending on the spec..

Comment: Hi Yohanes ,Thanks for your reply.Can you please tell me where I have to pass Base64 encoded string in this.