# getting public key null while converting string to public key

Tags: java, android

```
public static PublicKey strToPublicKey(String s) {

    PublicKey pbKey = null;
    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s));
        PEMReader pr = new PEMReader(br);
        Object obj = pr.readObject();

        if (obj instanceof PublicKey) {
            pbKey = (PublicKey) pr.readObject();
        } else if (obj instanceof KeyPair) {
            KeyPair kp = (KeyPair) pr.readObject();
            pbKey = kp.getPublic();
        }
        pr.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("CIPHER", e.getMessage());
    }
    return pbKey;
}
```

this line returns null value

```
pbKey = (PublicKey) pr.readObject();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
```

when I try to convert server key to rsa public key type 
it reurns null value at this line

```
pbKey = (PublicKey) pr.readObject();
```

Comment: did you tried to use the debugger breakpoint.

Comment: yes i got null at this line
pbKey = (PublicKey) pr.readObject();

Comment: Please check below [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371045/generating-publickey-from-base64-encoded-string), which Converts PublicKey from base64 String.

Comment: @PankajMundra He is using a higher level API, and one that doesn't just assume RSA, and there is no reason why he shouldn't.

Comment: This reader is for "X509 certificates, PKCS8 encoded keys and PKCS7 objects" in the formats used by OpenSSL.  Can you confirm that the input string is one of these? (or better yet, give an example input string?)

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense. You've already read the key. The `instanceof` test proves it. You should not be reading another object: you should be *casting* the object you already read.